# facebook sdk login not working in samsung devices android

Tags: java, android, facebook, single-sign-on

I am developing an application which is using facebook sdk for android to log in a user.
The app is working fine on htc handsets but there is an issue on samsung handsets :-

If there is a pre-installed Facebook official application in samsung phone then my facebook log into the app doesnt works. The application goes into dormancy state.
I even build the hash key and added it in my facebook app but still it is not working

please any help will be appreciated

Comment: in such a situation facebook-webview is not even called only onClick is being called and then nothing gets executed. OnComplete is not even reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an application using the Facebook SDK for Android running on a Samsung Galaxy S phone using this guide : http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/

Comment: the same model is not able to get users logged into my application also

Comment: no... actually non-tech guy was testing so i think he might have gone impatient for first time and banged the cell phone :) it started working though later anyways all good in hood :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem First of all I need to know which Key Hash value you entered on facebook app if it is 'ga0RGNYHvNM5d0SLGQfpQWAPGJ8=' then that is the problem. I think you entered "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64" this one on the terminal and you entered your own password to generate the key hash. if you done that please try do the following things also you enter the above command on terminal(I am using UBUNTU(linux). You type the command corresponding to which OS you are using) and enter the password as 'android'. This time you will get a different hey hash value. Copy that value and save it as the key hash value for your facebook app. After that check it is working or not. For me it worked. This will occur when we are using the debug key. After all this when you are about to publish this application on the Android market you will have to again change the key hash value according to the private key you are using. Try this may be this will help you.